# jfrog cli ssh authentication [Error:] unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Anyone experienced below error when using cli to search on artifactory repositories?  From time to time got below error (about 1 fail, 3 times successful).  Any ideas?

```
g Artifactory.
[Info:] Searching Artifactory using AQL query: items.find({"repo": "NONPROD_RPM","$or": [{"$and": [{"path": {"$match":"*"},"name":{"$match":"*"}}]}]}).include("name","repo","path","actual_md5","actual_sha1","size")
[Error:] Post ssh://artifactory.xyz.com:1339/api/search/aql: unsupported protocol scheme "ssh"
[Error:] Post ssh://artifactory.xyz.com:1339/api/search/aql: unsupported protocol scheme "ssh"
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to download an artifact using ssh keys. Interestingly error is after the authentication is done

Answer (score 0):

Your config file is having the problem. Most likely the ssh-key-path is not present or not correct in your jfrog-cli.conf file.
Please try to rename your jfrog-cli.conf file.

```
mv ~/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf ~/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf.old

/opt/jfrog/jfrog rt config --url ssh://artifactory.xyz.com:1339/ --ssh-key-path /user/<latomaster>/.ssh/id_rsa
```